# Bitwise inner product and orthogonality

Tags: inner-products, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I am confused about the definition of bitwise inner product used in quantum algorithms. For example, bitwise inner product of 01111 with itself (in mod2) gives us 0. But they are not orthogonal to each other. How come the inner product is 0? Am I missing a point here?

Comment: The problem is that the space of bit strings is vector space over a *finite* field. (In particular, it is a field of characteristic 2.) In such vector fields, there are many "intuitions" from vector fields over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ that no longer apply.  You've identified one of them.

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer So the interpretation of the notion of orthogonality of a vector space over strings of finite length is different than that of real vector spaces? Even the notion of vector changes then. That means if x and y are two binary strings, their bitwise inner product being 0 doesn’t intuitively refer to orthogonality in the real vector space sense.

Comment: Sorry for the (very) late reply... This does not change the notion of vectors in a vector space. There is just no notion of "orthogonality" in this space since there is no inner product. In order for a vector space over a field F to have an inner product, the field F needs to be *ordered*.

Comment: The definition of a vector space does not mention anything about inner products (see, e.g. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorSpace.html). Your space of bitstrings is the vector space over the field of two elements {0,1}. In order to a vector space over a field $F$ to have an inner product, the field $F$ must be *ordered*. Finite fields cannot be ordered.

Comment: I apologise as well for my late reply. The situation got more complicated now. Why is it that finite fields cannot be ordered? Every set can be well-ordered by the Well-Ordering Theorem (i.e. equivalent form of the Axiom of Choice).

Comment: The ordering in a field must be compatible with the field operations. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field. Also see the page for inner product spaces: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space

Comment: @luftbahnfahrer It's not merely about "intuitions", I think. An inner product has some general properties, for any vector space over some field. The question is : isn't a requirement for any well defined inner product that $\langle x,x\rangle \iff x =0$ ? If so, then the dot procut over a binary vector (in GF(2) ) does not seem to be an inner product.

Comment: @leonbloy You are correct (although I assume you meant to say that $\langle x,x\rangle =0\,\Longleftrightarrow \,x=0$). A similar argument shows that the dot product on any vector space over any finite field is not an *inner* product. Regarding my comment on "intuitions," I merely wanted to point out that there is no longer a notion of "orthogonality" in such vector spaces. Orthogonality of vectors is a useful idea when thinking about vectors in real (or complex) vector spaces, but not in vector spaces over finite fields. OP was asking about orthogonality and was "missing a point" (his words).

Answer (score 5):

- The bitwise dotproduct $x \cdot y$ tells you how many $1$ bits $x$ has in common with $y$.
- Then, $x \cdot x$ tells you how many $1$ bits $x$ has (since they are all in common).
- The bitwise dotproduct $x \cdot y \mod 2$ tells you whether the number of $1$ bits $x$ has in common with $y$ is odd ($1$) or even ($0$).
- Then,  $x \cdot x \mod 2$ tells you whether $x$ has an even (0) or odd (1) number of $1$ bits.

In your example, $01111$ has four $1$ bits, so the number of bits is even and $x \cdot x \mod 2 =0$.

If you change the leading $0$ in your example to a $1$ to get $11111$, there are an odd number (five) $1$s, so you expect $x \cdot x \mod 2 = 1$. This is in fact the case:

$1\cdot1 + 1\cdot1 + 1\cdot1 + 1\cdot1 + 1\cdot1 \mod 2\\ = 5 \mod 2 \\= 1.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be two n-bits integers, the bitwise inner product modulo $2$,  denoted $x \cdot y$, of $x$ and $y$ is given by the following sum $$x_1y_1 + \cdots + x_ny_n \;\text{mod}\,2.$$

So, the bitwise inner product of $01111$ with itself is $$0.0 + 1.1 + 1.1 + 1.1 +1.1 = 0 \; \text{mod}\,2.$$

Comment: That does not answer his question.

Comment: @Rab: the main question of the OP was "How come the inner product is 0?". So, it answers the question.

Comment: But the inner product of a binary string with itself shouldn’t give 0 unless the string is all 0’s. For this example, 01111 cannot be orthogonal to itself. But the result of the inner product is still 0. Does that mean 01111 is orthogonal to itself? Or is there a special way to treat binary strings as vectors?

Comment: @acevik: don't forget that it's the bitwise inner product "modulo 2", as far as I know it's only a convenient notation for some powers of (-1) in some quantum algorithms (hence the mod 2 operation). In particular, it does not behave anymore like an inner product on a vector space, and in this case orthogonality simply does not make sense.